# nodejs & JS 'split' methods return different results

Tags: node.js, fs

**split a text from a txt file(utf16le ，environment is macos);**

i use fs read the aaa.txt ,and split('\n\n'),the result length is 1.
i render the data on page, and use jquery read the content ,use split('\n\n'), the result length is 6(right result)

the aaa.txt

```
1�
�
�a�
�
�
�
�2�
�
�b�
�
�
�
�3�
�
�c�
�
�d�
�
�
�
�4�
�
�e�
�
�
�
�5�
�
�f�
�
�
�
�6�
�
�g�
�
```

node code:

```
 fs.readFile(__dirname+'/aaa.txt','utf16le',function (err,data) {
if(err){console.log(err);}
else {
  // console.log(data);
  // console.log(data);
  var textSubtitles = data.split('\n\n');
  console.log('length');
  console.log(textSubtitles.length);// the result is 1！！！
  res.render('aaa.ejs', {
        content:data
    })
}
```

jquery code:

```
 let sss = $('#fff').text().split('\n\n');
```

console.log(sss.length);// the result is 6！！！

sss is the data render by nodejs, the same text.

Comment: is `data` a buffer? What happens if you do `data.toString().split('\n\n')`

Comment: @GlenKeane nodejs `console.log(data.toString().split('\n\n').length);`  is 1

Comment: remove the encoding string & try again

Comment: `  fs.readFile(__dirname+'/aaa.txt',function (err,data) {  console.log(textSubtitles.length) })`  the result is 1, and the jquery result change to 19 ( is 6 if use 'utf16le')

Comment: i need to use split('\r\n\r\n') instead split('\n\n') thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is because the string from text is

`[ '1\r\na\r\n\r\n2\r\nb\r\n\r\n3\r\nc\r\nd\r\n\r\n4\r\ne\r\n\r\n5\r\nf\r\n\r\n6\r\ng\r\n' ]`

i need to use split('\r\n\r\n') instead split('\n\n')